# Button click event not firing inside modal pop up extender

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I have used ajax modal popup extender inside grid view for adding confirmation box for confirming user to delete an item from the grid view.

```
   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
                                                                                       <ItemTemplate>           
   ....
   ....                                                                                         <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" runat="server" ToolTip="Delete" CssClass="colorlnkbtndelete" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval (Container.DataItem, "Product") %>'><i class="icon-trash"></i></asp:LinkButton>

                                          <ajax:ConfirmButtonExtender ID="cnfbtn" TargetControlID="lnkDelete" DisplayModalPopupID="ModalPopupExtender"
                                                runat="server">
                                            </ajax:ConfirmButtonExtender>
                                            <asp:Panel ID="pnlConfirm" runat="server" Style="display: none" CssClass="pnlCss Filterpopup Containerpopup">
                                                <Con:Confirm ID="UserConfirm" runat="server" />
                                                <div class="footer2">
                                                    <asp:Button ID="btnOk" class="btn btn-danger" runat="server" Text="Yes" OnClick="Lbtn_Delete_Click" />
                                                    <asp:Button ID="btnCancelConfirm" class="btn btn-danger" runat="server" Text="No" />
                                                </div>
                                            </asp:Panel>
                                            <ajax:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="lnkDelete"
                                                PopupControlID="pnlConfirm" CancelControlID="btnCancelConfirm" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
                                            </ajax:ModalPopupExtender>

                                                                            </ItemTemplate>

                                                                            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Now the issue is that when we click on btnOK the event "Lbtn_Delete_Click" not getting fired. Please help !!!

Comment: You have set `pnlConfirm`  to `display:none'`

Comment: i removed it, the problem is still there... The problem is with ok button event. When the pop up is displayed there and user will click ok button the event "Lbtn_Delete_Click" is not getting fired

Answer (score 0):

is it under update panel? if yes you may add trigger.

if no,  just remove "Lbtn_Delete_Click" and switch to design mode and double click on button. and try.

Comment: it is in update panel but the button is in item tempate of grid view

Comment: I added postback enabled true by using scriptmanager, now it throws Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.

Comment: For debugging just click on popup ok button and press f12 keyboard button there may you found javascript error in console.